# Reshaping png image read by skimage.imread return ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

It works fine using a 616x346 png image as input in the following code:

```
from skimage import io

image = io.imread('img.png')
image = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3)
```

...but if I change the image dimensions to say 640x451, I get the error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1154560 into shape (288640,3)

Any thouhts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of 640x451 image you are trying to reshape is `(640, 451, 4)` instead of `(640, 451, 3)`. That's why you won't be able to convert it to `(640*451, 3)`. Have a look at the output of `image.shape` in both the 616x346 and 640x451 cases. One workaround is to convert it to rgb from rgba first -

```py
from skimage import io, color
image = io.imread('img.png')
image = color.rgba2rgb(image)
image = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3)
```

Comment: But why does the image add an alpha channel just by changing the pixel dimensions? Or do I misunderstand it?

Comment: The image already had the alpha channel without your changes @user3607022

Comment: But the image.shape of the initial 616x346 yields (616, 346, 3) - doesn't that mean there's no alpha channel?

Comment: You are talking about two different images right? The first image should be RGB and the second image should be RGBA in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, it's the same image. However as I open it in paint and slightly change the dimensions and re-save it perhaps paint saves it with an alpha channel...